# I have my Ubuntu installed on a 100GB partition in a 1TB SSD, I am running out of space

Tags: disk-management

I have created a 500GB partition and mounted it in my `/home` but I'm still getting from my OS low disk space.

Results of `lsblk` :

[image: lsblk]

Comment: Better to post full 'lsblk -f` output as code/text not png to preserve formatting in question. You can move /home to new partition. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving Or move some data to a data partition & link into /home. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: Also add the output of `df -h` (as text, using code formatting: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) and `sudo du -hxd1 /`)

Comment: @oldfred thanks a lot!
Moved /home to the new partition using provided link.